# how to check what packages are used to include in a requirements.txt file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm starting to dive into python but I'm a bit confused with how the requirements.txt file work. How do I know what to include in it?

For example, the current project I'm working on, I only installed Flask. So do I just add only flask to that file? Or are there other packages that I don't know about - if so is there a way to find out (e.g display a full list)?

Comment: Look at [`pip freeze`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-freeze) if you are using pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run `pip` to get the list of requirements for your project.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Comment: yeah that worked. thank you! Does that file automatically updates as I go along or will I have to do that manually?

Comment: you will need to manage it as you go, it does not automatically update by default. As per John's answer, you may benefit from using `virtualenv`'s so that you control just what you need for your specific app. You don't want to be freezing modules into your requirements that are part of another project or your system defaults. The app should be standalone so that if you send it to another developer, they can just `pip intall -r requirements.txt` and have everything your app needs, without installing anything unrelated.

Comment: Research specifically the `--no-site-packages` argument for `virtualenv` and how to switch between multiple projects, once you get the hang of it, you'll appreciate the modularity of it

Answer (score 1):

You could just "grep" the Python source files in your project for "import " to get an exhaustive list of packages you use.  Remove the obvious ones that are part of the standard library, like `datetime` or whatever, and the rest are what you might include in requirements.txt.

I don't know of a more "automatic" way to do it; another way might be to set up a clean virtualenv or other sandboxed install of Python with no extra packages, and try installing your software in there using only your requirements.txt.